# overwriting in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
<div id='tbl'> </div>

<script lang="Javascript">
var gd = new Array(16);
var a=0;
for(a=0; a<16; a++)
    gd[a] = new Array(16);
var sd = new Array(16);
for(a=0; a<16; a++)
    sd[a] = new Array(16);

var b1=0, b2=0;
for(b1=0; b1<16; b1++)
{
    for(b2=0; b2<16; b2++)
    {
        gd[b1][b2]="A";
        sd[b1][b2]="A";
    }
}

var c1=0, c2=0;
var score=0;

ble = "<center><table>";
for(c1=0; c1<16; c1++)
{
    ble += "<tr>";
    for(c2=0; c2<16; c2++)
    {
        ble += "<td onClick='changeColor(this)'>" + gd[c1][c2] + "</td>";
    }
    ble += "</tr>";
}
ble += "</table></center>";

document.getElementById('tbl').innerHTML = ble;

function changeColor(tdd)
{
    if(tdd.bgColor=='white')
    {
        tdd.bgColor='red'; 

        alert(c1);
        /*if (gd[c1][c2] == sd[c1][c2])
            score+=5;
        else
            score-=2;*/
    }
    else
    {
        tdd.bgColor='white'; 
    }
}
function scc()
{
    document.getElementById('scf').innerHTML = score;
}
</script>
<br><br><center><button type='button' onclick='scc()'> Click to see current score</button> <div id="scf">0</div> </center>
</body>
```

In the code given above, is there any way to get `c1` and `c2` current values in changeColor function instead of =16.

Otherwise, is there a way to write into the document so that it won't be overwritten every time?

Comment: you should start using readable variable names

Comment: **What are you trying to do?** `c1` `c2`, `gd`, `sd` don't say much!!!

Comment: And using `appendChild`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can pass them to your function call:

```
ble += "<td onClick='changeColor(this, " + c1 + ", " + c2 + ")'>" + gd[c1][c2] + "</td>";
```

Don't forget to declare new arguments in your function:

```
function changeColor(tdd, c1, c2)
```